# Efficient way to use locale sensitive strings as keys to a data structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, localization, internationalization

What is the most efficient way to key a data-structure using locale sensitive strings.

I essentially want a sorted TreeMap with the comparison algorithm for the sort being `a.localeCompare(b, locale, { sensitivity: 'base' })`.

The ideal method would be to have some sort of normalize/conversion such that `a.convert() === b.convert()` for all `a` and `b` where `a.localeCompare(b, ...)` returns 0. Then I could use the result of that conversion as the key for a hashMap like javascript objects or Map.

Alternatively is there a known sorted TreeMap where I could specify the comparison of the keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [npm parameterize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parameterize) library to create a locale insensitive key. The function provided takes a utf-8 string and turns it into a relatively readable lowercase string. This then can be used for a hash code in a hashmap. So 'Résumé' and 'resume' would both map to the same item in the hashmap.

Comment: @Elikill58 hope the edit makes it more clear.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect !